# Obtaining the name of a variable as a string

Tags: functions, evaluation, variable-definitions

Suppose that I have an arbitrary variable `myVariable`.  Is there some function `fun` -- either built-in or one that I can define -- that will return a *string* "myVariable" when I pass it `myVariable`?

I would like the output...

```
myVariable = 123456;
fun[myVariable]
```

...to give the output...

> `"myVariable"`

... (a string output) for some function `fun`.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Looks like you need `SymbolName[Unevaluated[myvar]]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can give the function one of the `Hold` `Attributes`.

```
SetAttributes[fun, HoldFirst]
```

Then as Leonid suggested

```
fun[var_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated@var]
```

Without the hold attribute, this will not work.

Answer (score 7):

Any of these could be a start:

```
ToString@((Trace@myVariable)[[1]])
```

Or:

```
StringCases[ToString[Hold[myVariable]],RegularExpression["Hold\\[([[:print:]]+)\\]"] -> "$1"][[1]]
```

Comment: You don't need to use StringCases/regex if you use `HoldForm` instead of `Hold`