# ToString get local name of the symbol

Tags: string-manipulation, packages, symbols

I am using `ToString` to convert symbols to a string. So my entire code is written assuming `ToString[a]` will return `"a"`. Now I am converting my notebook to Mathematica package. Now `ToString[a]` returns `` "Packagename`Private`a" ``. This breaks my assumptions and so my code breaks;

Is there anyway to tweak like `ToStringSafe[a]` that returns `a` e.g. the **local** name of that symbol. Not the *global* one.

Comment: Take a look at `SymbolName`

Comment: related: [32223](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32223/5478), [15687](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15687/5478), [119922](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119922/5478), [17916](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17916/5478)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymbolName.html).

```
foo`bar
(* foo`bar *)

ToString[foo`bar]
(* "foo`bar" *)

SymbolName[foo`bar]
(* "bar" *)
```

Warning:

Converting between symbols and strings requires great care, especially when different contexts are involved.  Make sure you really need to do this and that you really do not want the fully qualified name.  Robust code will not normally convert between strings and symbols.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the warning. What did you mean by different contexts ? Did you mean different scopes or different namespaces ?

Comment: @NeelBasu There is no such thing as "local name" or "global name". When you used these words I started to wonder if you have a good understanding of [contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html) and [name resolution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12).  Contexts are kind of like namespaces but not exactly.