# Get the name of symbol inside a function

Tags: functions, evaluation, variable-definitions

I have a list `t1Funcsv0={0.10000000000, 1.00000*10^-7}` and I have a function

```
Maximum[functions_, min_, max_, type_] := (
Which[
Flatten[Position[functions, Max[functions]]], 
Max[functions] == nt,
Flatten[Position[functions, nt]], 
RankedMax[functions, 2] == nt,
Flatten[{Position[functions, Max[functions]],Position[functions,nt]}],
True, 
Print["Error Maximum"]])
```

to which I pass t1Funcsv0 as well as other arguments. I would like to get the name of the symbol "t1Funcsv0" inside the function Maximum.
I tried to use `SymbolName[Unevaluated@functions]` as I found in [Obtaining the name of a variable as a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/obtaining-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Get the name of a symbol passed to a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/get-the-name-of-a-symbol-passed-to-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it doesn't work because "functions" is already evaluated

Comment: In the [post you linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15689/9490) you see that they give their function the attribute `HoldFirst`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I did. If I use  `Trace` I get `{t1Funcsv0,{0.10000000000, 1.00000*10^-7}}`

Comment: I think the answer here is better at and much clearer then the one here [Get the name of a symbol passed to a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/get-the-name-of-a-symbol-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a `Hold` attribute if you want access to the symbol name during evaluation:

```
Attributes[myfunc] = HoldFirst;
myfunc[arg1_, arg2_] := (
  Print["The name of the first argument is ", SymbolName[Unevaluated[arg1]]];
  Print["The value of the first argument is ", arg1];
  Print["The max of the first argument is ", Max[arg1]];
  Print["The second argument is ", arg2]
  )

t1Funcsv0 = {0.10000000000, 1.00000*10^-7}
myfunc[t1Funcsv0, bob]
```

> The name of the first argument is t1Funcsv0
>
> The value of the first argument is {0.1,1.*10^-7}
>
> The max of the first argument is 0.1
>
> The second argument is bob